# how to prevent "routeLoader$" from executing 2 x when using "resolveValue"?

Tags: qwik, qwikjs

See this example causes my "routeLoader$" to be clled 2 times, which is an issue for obvious reasons?
I couldnt understad how to prevent this.

Please help:

```
export const useNewsLoader = routeLoader$(async () => {
  return {
    data: 'example'
  };
})

export const head: DocumentHead = ({ resolveValue }) => {
  const newsData = resolveValue(useNewsLoader);
  ...
};

export default component$((props) => {
  const newsData = useNewsLoader();
  ...
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the Qwik source code and **resolveValue** is using the previous response. I also did this example to verify my thesis. In the console you can see the same random number.

```
export const useNewsLoader = routeLoader$(async () => {
    // I also tested with a real endpoint and I saw one call
    // const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5173/api/test');
    const random = Math.random();
    console.log('1',random);
    return {test: random};
});

export const head: DocumentHead = ({ resolveValue }) => {
    const newsData = resolveValue(useNewsLoader);
    console.log('2',newsData.test );
    return {
        title: `${newsData.test}`,
        meta: [],
    };
};

export default component$(() => {
    const newsData = useNewsLoader();
    return <div></div>;
});
```

Comment: I check myself again, and i am confused bcs. my fetch to external server is still happening 2 times... so the routeLoader$ is triggered multiple times.

Comment: Do you have a public repo to share please?

Comment: its seems some other code parts was causing this issue, sorry!